# how to get the background color in vim?

Tags: vim, colors, color-scheme

Is it possible to get the background color of the current color scheme in vim?

I tried `:hi Normal` but the response isn't helpful: `Normal     xxx cleared`

Comment: `Normal     xxx cleared` means that there's no `Normal` color.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there's a way, it's through `:hi Normal` (or rather `:echo synIDattr(hlID("Normal"), "bg")`, which avoids the need to capture the command output); I don't know about any other means, e.g. a dedicated `getbgcolor()` function. For me, this works fine (in Windows GVIM):

```
Normal         xxx guibg=#FFFBF0 font=Courier:h10:cANSI
```

If the `guibg` attribute doesn't appear, I guess that means that the (operating system's) default background color is used; i.e. nothing has been set.

Comment: [...] If the `guibg` attribute doesn't appear, I guess that means that the (operating system's) default background color is used; i.e. nothing has been set. [...]  
Thanks, that was the issue!